# How to add recurring class in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a gym class app, owner should be able to add classes and set it to "every week"/"every day" etc, and allow member to book.

In my mind the data structure look like this.

```
Classes
└───Yoga Class ID
    └───Date1
        └───Max member allowed
        └───Member A
        └───Member B
    └───Date2
└───Aerobic Class ID
    └───Date1
    └───Date2
```

I think I can write code to add it a specific time maybe 52 for weekly class so it create classes for the following year, but is there a better way to achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no singular correct way to model this, it all depends on how you want to use the data in your app. Generating the 52 calendar item documents may be the perfect solution for your use-cases.

One common alternatively I'd consider would be to store the initial calendar event as a document that has the repetition schedule in it. I'd still generate documents for the other 51 calendar events, but then have them contain a field that refers back to the original document. That way you can more easily find all documents for the repeating event with a query.

There are many more options to consider, but as said: they all depend on the use-cases you want to implement. To get more comfortable with these and other considerations when modeling data in NoSQL databases, I'd recommend:

- Reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).
- Watching [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).
- Watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), which is a bit older and for the other Firebase Realtime Database, but has some great examples of mapping SQL logic to NoSQL.

Comment: Thank you very much Frank. The alternative method is a really great approach that I haven't thought of.